# XSLT: general versus specific tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to write an XML -> CSV transform, and am not sure how to write a template that applies to all elements with a general name syntax INCLUDING one that has a separate, specific template. Here's my code:

```
<xsl:template match="dc:subject">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&#13;\n', '; ')"/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="dc:*">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(), $quote)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With the XML to be transformed:

```
<dc:title>Title</dc:title>
<dc:subject>Dogs&#13;
Cats&#13;
Rabbits</dc:subject>
<dc:description>An adorable gathering of animals</dc:description>
<dc:date>2018 Oct 1</dc:date>
```

output to:

```
"Title","Dogs; Cats; Rabbits;","An adorable gathering of animals","2018 Oct 1"
```

I've tried putting this in a few different orders and also throwing in `<xsl:apply-templates match="dc:subject">` on the latter or `<xsl:apply-templates match="dc:*">` on the former, but it's still not putting the subject material in quotes/with the delimiter. I know I can kludge this by just adding that into the `dc:subject` template, but I'd rather do it right and I'm sure it's something pretty simple!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did not mention your input XML as well as your desired output XML. Adding both would approximate a [mcve].

Comment: With normal processing, in one mode only one template will be applied to any matched node. Unless you happen to use XSLT 2 or 3 and can use `<xsl:next-match/>` where needed (well, there is also `<xsl:apply-imports/>` if you want to apply imported template rules).

Comment: Edited to add example XML input and CSV output. Martin, thanks for the heads-up about next-match - this is 2.0, so I should be able to give that a try.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Okay, maybe I'm not putting next-match in the right place? I guess what I want to do is to apply one template to the output of another so that I get `"Dogs; Cats; Rabbits;"` rather than `"Dogs Cats Rabbits"Dogs; Cats; Rabbits;`

Answer (score 0):

One way using `xsl:next-match` is

```
  <xsl:template match="dc:subject">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&#13;\n', '; ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dc:*" priority="2">
       <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><xsl:next-match/><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I also had to explicitly raise the priority of the template outputting the quotes as only that way it will be used first. Obviously the use of `xsl:next-match` requires there to be a default text only copy of the contents of any `dc:*` not being `dc:subject` but the normal stylesheet, built-in rules do that anyway, so assuming you have not overriden that elsewhere the above should work.

Online sample is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwQ/1.

The request "what I want to do is to apply one template to the output of another" is only possible if you use a variable or chain stylesheets.

I don't know if you can be sure that your `dc:*` elements contain a single text node (and not data separated by comments or processing instructions like `<dc:foo>fo<!-- comment -->o</dc:foo>`), but if you are sure there is only a single text node then matching on the element to output the quotes with e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="dc:subject/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&#13;\n', '; ')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dc:*">
       <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

is also possible and doesn't need setting any match priority: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwQ/2

Both examples don't take into account the `normalize-space()` you also seem to want to do based on your sample, I think you could add `<xsl:template match="dc:*/text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>` to handle that but would also be required to use `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(., '&#13;\n', '; '))"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&#13;\n', '; ')"/>` if the `dc:subject` text also needs the white space normalization.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Welp, that puts the semicolons in the quotes the way I wanted, and blanks the output of all other fields, so I will...be looking more into that :)

Comment: Okay, so yes, @Martin Honnen, I'm not sure how to proceed. I can avoid blanking the output of the other fields by adding `<xsl:template match="dc:*/text()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>`, but besides template conflict errors, it also no longer puts in the semicolons! So, still looking for a way to do both...